# not able to use bean:define variable in non stuts tags in a jsp page

Tags: jsp, jstl, struts-1

I am able to use "acctNum" inside scriptlet as <%=acctNum %> with in the block of statements inside  tag as mentioned in the below code.

```
<logic:greaterEqual name="childArraySize" value="1">
 <bean:define id="acctNum" name="overviewSel" property="accountNumber" type="String"/>
 <logic:equal name="accountNumber" value="<%=acctNum %>">
    <bean:define id="STItemIndex" name="ItemIndex"/>
    <bean:define id="overviewCh" name="overviewSel" type="com.beans.statements.StatementAccount"/>
    <bean:define id="arraySize"  name="childArraySize"/>
    <bean:define id="statementAccountTypeDesc" name="statementAccountTypeDescSel"/>
  </logic:equal>    
</logic:greaterEqual>
```

But I'm not able to use this in the code anywhere after `</logic:greaterEqual>`
it gives me intermittent error when using it in a scriptlet i.e., inside `<% --- %>`, I am getting '*acctNum can not be resolved*'

But it works if I use it in any struts tag like `<bean:write name="acctNum">`

Please let me know if there is a work around for this

Comment: It is your IDE which is not recognizing that variable. Anyways if you running the application, it will work perfectly if any other errors are not there.

Comment: thanks for the reply NavSoft, I'm using RAD 7.5, But its occurring quite often, I cant risk to move it to Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.

I found that all stuts tags are fine with getting the values, but if I'm using scriptlet/ JSTL tags I was not getting the values,

For that I had to do a workaround and use it like this `<%pageContext.getAttribute("acctNum") %>` in case of a scriptlet
and 
for JSTL `<c:out value="pageContext.acctNum">`

Comment: is that same like <%=acctNum%> ?