# checking if a bean is null using javascript or other methods

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts

The below code snippets work when the values used to create myBean is not null.

How do I take care of the scenario when `myBean` has null value? Is there a way to check the bean's value?

```
<bean:define id="myBean" name="<%=myName%>" property="<%=myProp%>"/>
```

now if `myName` and/or `myProp` is null,

**Error** `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Define tag cannot set a null value` error.

**Attempted solution:**

```
<c:if test="${not empty myBean}">
            <bean:define id="myBean" name="<%=myName%>" property="<%=myProp%>"/>
            </c:if>
```

Comment: what doesn't work ? You mean you get a js var myBean value as 'null' string and you want to avoid that ?

Comment: edited, sorry if i wasn't clear

Comment: Hi [this link][1] will bw helpful.This is just a guess


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14648106/1069633

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@bouncingHippo Use struts logic tag for this null checking purpose. Like,

```
<logic:present name="<%=myName%>" property="<%=myProp%>">
   <bean:define id="myBean" name="<%=myName%>" property="<%=myProp%>"/>
</logic:present>
```

Let me know if this helps..

Answer (score 1):

EDITED as per additional information provided:

```
<c:if test="${not empty myName}">
... your bean def
</c:if>
```

Ignore: or maybe something like this: ${empty myBean} or ${not empty myBean} ??

Comment: that is if your myName is available to the EL.

Comment: i tried your method (i pasted my code for your solution) above. and it still throws the same error..

Comment: is myName or myProp null ?? does the bean have proper getters/setters ?

Comment: @bouncingHippo what you are trying to do here is get the value of property myProp from the bean myName and make it available through myBean. Check what is missing in your code.